# get_post random and order by not working

Tags: get-posts

I have this code that returns list of post title as links, but when I add the 'orderby' and 'order' parameters - it returns results but 'orderby, order, rand' do not work, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<ul>
   <?php $post; $cat_posts = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 10, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'order' => ASC, 'category' => $disciplineCatID));
   foreach($cat_posts as $post) : ?>
   <?php $postTitle = get_the_title(); if($title != $postTitle) :?>
   <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">&rsaquo;&rsaquo; <?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
   <?php endif ;?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Missing single quotes on the `ASC`.. just a typo or possibly related?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what's not working (e.g. does your code not return any results or ...)?

Comment: @t31los, tried the quotes - thanks but still no luck.
@Manzabar - thank you - I've updated the information. Results are returned 'order, orderby, rand' do not take effect. Thanks you.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, this is the correct syntax:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

However plugins can keep this from working properly. Try disabling **ALL** plugins and see if that helps. Two known plugins which keep `orderby=rand` from working are `Post Type Order` and `WP_Sticky`

Also, if you have Post Types order installed make sure you visit the Admin page and check the settings. You can use this plugin and keep it from automatically re-ordering posts:

http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/2616/pictureot.png

And then you can use the code for Post Types Order to specifically order those posts in places where you need them to be ordered via the custom/menu-order. Here is the example code for that plugin:

The following PHP code will still return the post in the set-up Order:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'feature'
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_query->have_posts())
{
$my_query->the_post();
(..your code..)          
}
```

Or:

```
$posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($posts as $post)
{
(..your code..)     
}
```

If the Auto Sort is uncheck you will need to use the "orderby" and "order" parameters:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'feature',
'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
'order'     => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. "Intuitive Custom Posts Order" definitely causes this problem!

Comment: This was oddly specific and right. Post Types Order did it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not using that plugin, but many of the examples on wordpress.org use "sort_order" instead of "order", which didn't work, whereas this does. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you're hosted on WP Engine, you need to manually enable random ordering in your settings or else `'orderby' => 'rand'` won't work.

https://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/random-order-wpengine/

Comment: thanks that one helped.

Comment: After at least an hour of frustration ... THANK YOU!!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I am sure you saved me an hour or two!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to use [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) instead?

Something like:

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order'    => 'ASC'
);
query_posts( $args );
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help, silly me - it was conflicting with a plugin 'Post Type Order' (Order Post Types Objects using a Drag and Drop Sortable javascript capability)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php 
   remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');
   query_posts('orderby=rand'); 
?>
```

got the answer from here

http://www.reinaris.nl/wp/wordpress-random-post-order-not-working-orderbyrand/

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to `setup_postdata` inside your `foreach` loop to get template tags to work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and luckily found this thread. I tried a different fix, probably dirtier than the others, but maybe useful in some cases.

Basically, I [shuffled](http://php.net/manual/it/function.shuffle.php) the posts before outputting them:

```
<?php 
    $selectedPosts = get_posts($args);
    shuffle($selectedPosts);

    foreach ($selectedPosts as $selectedPost) : 
    setup_postdata( $selectedPost );
?>

<!-- post elements here -->

<?php 
    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have wp-engine in your WordPress site check the ALLOW ORDER BY RAND() option. See an article here: https://wpengine.co.uk/support/about-order-by-rand/